# How to calculate average row creation time in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In my table i have a 'created_at' column which automatically filled with the time each row is created at.

I want to know how to get the average (second) creation time for the last 10 / 100 or 1000 row.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thank you.

EDIT
I'm sorry if the question was not clear, i already have the data, i want to know what is the average created_at of each row.

EDIT - SAMPLE DATA
Here i select only ID and created_at column for the last 10 row. how can i get the average time difference in second of that last 10 second row ?

```
2993    2018-06-14 01:33:12
2992    2018-06-14 01:33:08
2991    2018-06-14 01:33:04
2990    2018-06-14 01:32:59
2989    2018-06-14 01:32:55
2988    2018-06-14 01:32:52
2987    2018-06-14 01:32:47
2986    2018-06-14 01:32:44
2985    2018-06-14 01:32:40
2984    2018-06-14 01:32:35
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you search for the average time it took your db to complete a specific INSERT operation?

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was not clear, i already have the data, i want to know what is the average created_at of each row.

Comment: Please provide those data so we can understand you better. I still don't get what you mean.

Comment: sample data added, kindly please check updated question

Comment: and thank you for the down voters , i hope you have better thing to do in your life :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write query that inserts 1000 rows and see how long it took - for example Mysql Workbench gives you time each query took by default.

You also probably could write some hooks that would calculate time for you for all queries and insert it into some table. And then you could do all kinds of statistical analysis using that table. But it would slow down your database...

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was not clear, i already have the data, i want to know what is the average created_at of each row.